# bundling moon.lua dependency

Tags: lua, love2d, moonscript

I'm making a game in lua with Love2D and have successfuly bundled it into an .exe for distributon. However, I recently switched to moonscript, and now after compiling and bundling the executable can't start on another computer because it doesn't have `moon.lua` (I guess it wants that for the standard library).

How can I include the moonscript standard library into my .exe fused bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy that file directly into your codebase the same way you've included any other libraries that you're using for your game when packaging for distribution.

**Note**: within MoonScript's code base the `moon` library is actually the file `moon/init.lua`. Lua's package loader can find a module `NAME` by loading the file `NAME/init.lua`. This will not work for the current directly lookup though. The easiest fix is to rename `init.lua` to `moon.lua`.

https://github.com/leafo/moonscript/blob/master/moon/init.lua

Comment: Hm, but don't you think I need to require `moonscript/util.lua`too? `init.lua` requires that.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I forgot that there was a dependency to the `moon` library. Yeah, you'll need to include that file as well.